# How to replace this slow filtering function using a faster pandas-only approach?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, dataframe

Here's what I'd like to do:

On this DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Entry', 'Exit'], data=np.array([[257, 259],
   [259, 260],
   [270, 271],
   [271, 273],
   [272, 274],
   [305, 305],
   [317, 320],
   [323, 326],
   [324, 326],
   [325, 328],
   [326, 329],
   [335, 337]]), index=[3509, 3511, 3522, 3523, 3524, 3557, 3569, 3575, 3576, 3577, 3578, 3587])
```

I'd like to have each row marked (to later use it as a mask) where the 'Entry' value is higher than any 'Exit' value before the current row. But only considering 'Exit' values of rows for which that condition has not already been True.

The first idea I came up with won't really do the job, as it ignores the second condition:

```
df['NoTradeFirst'] = np.where(df.Entry < df.Exit.cummax().shift(1), 1, 0)
```

So I came up with the following function:

```
def find_no_trade_bars(s):
    last = 0
    no_trades = list()

    for entry, exit in s.items():
        if entry >= last:
            last = exit
        else:
            no_trades.append(entry)

    return(no_trades)

no_trades = find_no_trade_bars(df[['Entry', 'Exit']].set_index('Entry').Exit)
df['ReallyNoTrade'] = np.where(df.Entry.isin(no_trades), 1, 0)
```

Which when called results in the following DF:

[image: DataFrame Result]

As expected 'NoTradeFirst' gets it almost right with the exception of 'Entry' 326 which should be 0 instead of 1 as the previous rows 'Exit' should be ignored as the condition was already true for that previous row.

I'm sure there's some way to do this, probably using .groupby() or some rolling function but I just couldn't figure it out on my own.

So hopefully someone knows how to do this the pandas/numpy way. My main goal here is a potential performance gain.

Thanks!

Marco

Comment: I don't think this is a vectorizable process, so numpy and pandas will have a tough time with it.  You might want to look into `itertools` if you want something efficient.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Could you give a precise definition? When you write "where the 'Entry' value is higher than any 'Exit' value before", I assume you actually mean "smaller"? When you write "But only considering 'Exit' values of rows for which that condition has not already been True." I assume you mean entries that have not been flagged already based on the previous conditions (i.e. not referring to whether the exit value has been used already for comparison)?

Comment: __Continuation:__ Also is your data structured somehow? From your example and your function I assume that for each data point `Entry <= Exit` and for each pair of data points `p1.Entry <= p2.Entry` if `p1` occurs previously to `p2` (i.e. data is sorted). Is that correct? In any case you want to perform a task that assigns a value to each item so the best you can get is `O(n)` and your function is already `O(n)`. So I don't see why you consider it slow at all.

Comment: It's slow because it uses many `for` loops, which can probably be replaced  by c code if you can find an `itertools` solution.  But digging a little it seems `pandas` and `itertools` don't play so well together.

Comment: @a_guest: yes you got it right. Higher means larger/bigger/greater than. So for example 2 is higher than 1. You're also right on your second assumption. I meant it just like that. Regarding structure, you don't have to worry about it, it's sorted yes. If there is a faster way I'd be happy about it as it would save me days of CPU time over the long run. Using a function like that is slow compared to "pure vectorized pandas".

Comment: @DanielForsman: right, getting the DF to itertools and then back will cost me more time than what I save by using itertools.

Comment: In general, if element `out[i]` is dependent on  `func(in[:i])`, it's not a vectorizable process, it's discrete dynamic one.  Sometimes number theory saves you and it's actually a hidden linear process, but not often, and I'm pretty sure it's not in this case.